# Preserve client source IP for Kubernetes ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using this Ingress it is similar to Nginx: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress_annotation#general

When I do:

```
request -> LoadBalancer Service -> client source public IP returned
request -> Ingress -> LoadBalancer Service -> some private IP returned
```

I would like to preserve the client source public IP. In my Service I am setting `ExternalTrafficPolicy: Local`, and it works when hitting the LoadBalancer directly, but I do not know what setting I require when going through the Ingress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For preserving Ingress source IP, see these steps: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-comm-ingress-annotations#preserve_source_ip_classic

Essentially you do the same thing that you've described, except that you edit the existing alb service.

---

steps:

- kubectl edit svc <ALB_ID> -n kube-system
- Under spec, change the value of externalTrafficPolicy from Cluster to Local.

Comment: This link is now broken. Can you edit the answer to include the procedure to follow?